# How can I run a process in one terminal from another terminal

Tags: terminal, background-process, process-management

I have 5 processes running from one terminal (`T1`). All of them are running in background, but generate a lot of output.

Now from other terminal (`T2`), I want to kill one of them using `KILL pid` command. Then after `60` secs, I want to restart the same process (this will get a different pid obviously).

My script would look like

```
KILL 1524
sleep 60
myProcess
```

The problem is that after this, the terminal `T2` also becomes unusable, due to outputs of the process. If I want to do the same thing again, I will have to start another terminal.  Is it possible to something that would force the process to start in `T1`?

Comment: Some ideas: write the output to a logfile and tail it - so it does not matter in what terminal you started the processes. Else you could look at screen and/or tmux those could solve the problem as well.

Comment: Can you put a `while :; do someprogram; sleep 60; done` loop around the program so after a kill it restarts itself?

Comment: You can not spawn processes the way you want, all precesses run by a shell are always child of such shell, to accomplish what you want you can redirect the output to a file appendnting `>my_file` or even to /dev/null if you dont care for the output `>/dev/null`, that way you will be able to continue using the same terminal.

Comment: This may not be what the questioner **needs**, but can you redirect a processes output to another terminal using `screen`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you *can* have the output appear in the other terminal—though I doubt you really want to. To do so:

1. Find the tty of the terminal you'd like the output to go to; the easiest way is to run `tty`. This should print something like: `/dev/pts/42`.
2. In the other terminal, run: `command > /dev/pts/42 &`. If you want to do stderr as well as stdout: `command > /dev/pts/42 2>&1 &`

That will only work for the same user (due to permissions), and it doesn't redirect input (and redirecting input won't really work, as you'll be fighting the shell for it).

A much better solution is to redirect the output to a file (`command > outfile`), then you can use `less`, `tail`, etc. to watch it. Or, use `screen`/`tmux` to run multiple sessions inside one terminal.

Comment: see also `nohup` and `sigstop`/`sigcont`,